# when i was update my mongodb data it will getting errors with 'Id' what the reason for that

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

This is React-js code, i just want to edit mongo DB table values through UI, when I was doing it it was an error with passing id value, but I did it with tutorial what is the reason for that??

```
trainsRoutes.route('/update/id').post(function (req, res) {
    Trains.findById(req.params.id, function (err, trains) {
        if (!trains)
            res.status(404).send("Ticket lot is not found");
        else {
            trains.train_name = req.body.train_name;
            trains.train_where = req.body.train_where;
            trains.train_to = req.body.train_to;
            trains.train_ticket_price = req.body.train_ticket_price;
            trains.train_ticket_quantity = req.body.train_ticket_quantity;

            trains.save().then(trains => {
                res.json('Update complete');
            })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.status(400).send("unable to update the database");
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like you may have missed a colon before `id`. `trainsRoutes.route('/update/:id')`

Comment: That is **not** react code. That is **nodejs** code.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? Also, the answer by @seanulus seems like one of the problems.